# Find values of $x$ such that at least one of the eigenvalues of the matrix is zero

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-completion

Given the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & x & 5 & -10 \\
-x & 10 & -x & 10 \\
-10 & -x & 10 & -5 \\
10 & -5 & -10 & -x
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I need to choose values of $x \in [-16,0]$ such that at least one of the eigenvalues of the matrix is zero.

Comment: Have you tried computing the determinant? A square matrix has $0$ determinant if and only if it has $0$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: Must $x \in \mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 1):

For a zero eigenvalue you need the determinant to be zero.

If you add the 3rd row to the 4th row you obtain $$0=\begin{vmatrix}0&x&5&-10 \\-x&10&-x&10\\-10&-x&10&-5\\0&-5-x&0&-5-x\\\end{vmatrix}$$
Therefore either $x=-5$ or
$$0=\begin{vmatrix}0&x&5&-10 \\-x&10&-x&10\\-10&-x&10&-5\\0&1&0&1\\\end{vmatrix}.$$  Now add multiples of Row 4 to the other rows to obtain $$0=\begin{vmatrix}0&10+x&5&0 \\-x&0&-x&0\\-10&5-x&10&0\\0&1&0&1\\\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}0&10+x&5 \\-x&0&-x\\-10&5-x&10\\\end{vmatrix}=-x\begin{vmatrix}0&10+x&5 \\1&0&1\\-10&5-x&10\\\end{vmatrix}$$

Therefore $x$ is $-7,-5$ or $0$.

Comment: Well, all this is way beyond my knowledge of math but after your answer, I can totally write a short python code to get the solution. It seems like it's 0 and -5? Thank you)

Comment: You're welcome. I got x=-7 as well by the way.

Comment: how come. are you sure about it?

Comment: Yes. I've added more working in to show this.

Comment: Omg right. Thank you

Comment: @YuliaKoroleva In what context did this problem come up if computing a determinant as is done here is “way beyond your knowledge of math?”

Comment: I may be exaggerated a bit when I said it was way beyond